# Grammatical query (was vs is, etc)

Tags: grammar, context

I live and work in Taiwan but my son has a question regarding grammar in his test. I don't quite know how to answer this or to help him, so I would like some advice, if possible:

"Despite the fact that a large number of foods made from these beans are sweet, the first chocolate drink actually tasted bitter and _____ created by the Mayan people."

A) was believed to be
B) was believed to have been
C) is believed to be
D) is believed to have been

I'm not sure. Could someone please help me and explain what the answer is and why?

Thank you!

Comment: Well. We still don't know to this day who actually created the drink (otherwise there's no point in mentioning that whole bit in the first place). So that rules out the first two options straight away. And out of the remaining two options, one is just nonsense.

Comment: @emlirara: Happy Chinese New Year.